# angular change view url parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to navigate to a different view in an angularjs app using url parameters.  I've tried something like this

```
<a href="" ng-click="goToDevice(treeCurrentNode.uuid)">{{treeCurrentNode.displayName}}</a>
```

js:

```
$location.path('/devices').search({resourceView: 'deviceDetailsView'})
                .search({explorerView: 'table'}).search({type: 'Device'}).search({uuid: uuid});
```

And something like this using `$stateProvider`

```
<a ui-sref="Devices({resourceView: 'deviceGroupView', explorerView: 'table', type: 'Device', uuid: treeCurrentNode.uuid})">{{treeCurrentNode.displayName}}</a>
```

My state provider code looks like this:

```
.state('Devices', {
    url: "/devices",
    params: {
        resourceView: null,
        explorerView: null,
        type: null,
        uuid: null
    },
    templateUrl: "app/main/devices/module/views/devices.html",
    controller: "DevicesExtendedCtrl",
    reloadOnSearch: false,
```

I also tried using the `$stateProvider` using `$state.go` like this

```
<a href="" ng-click="go(treeCurrentNode.uuid)">{{treeCurrentNode.displayName}}</a>
```

js:

```
$state.go('Devices', {resourceView: 'deviceDetailsView', explorerView: 'table', type: 'Device', uuid: uuid})
```

But the parameters are not being added to the url.  The url I'm taken to when I don't try to add parameters like this:

```
$location.path('/devices')
```

has the resourceView and explorerView parameters in there by default, but not the type and uuid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling `$location.search()` wrong, I changed it to `$location.search('uuid', uuid)` and it worked, no need to modify `stateProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change your `stateprovider` code as follows see if it works. It worked of me.

```
.state('Devices', {
    url: "/devices/:resourceView/:explorerView/:type/:uuid",
    params: {
        resourceView: null,
        explorerView: null,
        type: null,
        uuid: null
    },
    templateUrl: "app/main/devices/module/views/devices.html",
    controller: "DevicesExtendedCtrl",
    reloadOnSearch: false,
```

Comment: That is close.  I should have mentioned that the default url I'm directed to when I don't try to add any parameters already has resourceView and explorerView added as parameters.  When I change the code like this it has resourceView and explorerView as parameters but it adds type and uuid to the context path before the parameters

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using ui-router so you should define `url` property in your $stateProvider. It would looks like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('contacts.detail', {
        url: "/contacts/:contactId",
        templateUrl: 'contacts.detail.html',
        controller: function ($stateParams) {
            // If we got here from a url of /contacts/42
            expect($stateParams).toBe({contactId: "42"});
        }
    })
```

In this example we defined contactId paramater. `/contact/123` should match your url.

When you defining parameters using ui-router, you can use it by $stateParams.contactId.

More details you can find on https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-parameters